# How to migrate to a bigger SSD?

Tags: encryption, ssd, lvm

I'd like to migrate my Ubuntu 14.04 install from a smaller SSD (256GB) to a bigger one (Crucial MX100 512GB) without reinstalling.
What is the best way to process? I read that Clonezilla was not appropriate to deal with the SSD alignment.

More details about my install (a full encrypted install with LVM):

**`df -h`**

```
Filesystem                  Size Used Available Used% Mount on
/dev/mapper/rm--work--vg-root    23G     11G   12G  47% /
none                            4,0K       0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                            7,7G    4,0K  7,7G   1% /dev
tmps                            7,7G     74M  7,7G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                           1,6G    1,6M  1,6G   1% /run
none                            5,0M       0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                            7,7G    764K  7,7G   1% /run/shm
none                            100M     64K  100M   1% /run/user
tmpfs                           4,0G       0  4,0G   0% /var/cache/apt/archives
/dev/sda1                       228M     85M  132M  39% /boot
/dev/mapper/rm--work--vg-home   204G    189G  4,9G  98% /home
```

**`cat /etc/fstab`**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/aliot--work--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,discard 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=c15f5e23-e892-4f00-8744-2805ae304cf9 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/aliot--work--vg-home /home           ext4    defaults,noatime,discard        0       2
/dev/mapper/aliot--work--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

#tmp to ram
#tmpfs   /tmp       tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777   0  0
tmps /tmp tmpfs defaults,suid,nodev,exec 0 0

#/var/log/ to ram
#tmpfs /var/log tmpfs defaults,nosuid,nodev,noatime,mode=0755,size=5% 0 0

#apt cache to ram
tmpfs    /var/cache/apt/archives    tmpfs    defaults,size=4g    0    0

#cache to ram
tmpfs    /home/rm/.cache    tmpfs    defaults,size=1g    0    0
```

**`sudo lvdisplay`**

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/aliot-work-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                aliot-work-vg
  LV UUID                ym1lJD-aRxN-23NA-Wgs8-0YbP-ryIv-RWzY6v
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time aliot-work, 2013-06-24 14:29:45 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                7,86 GiB
  Current LE             2013
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/aliot-work-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                aliot-work-vg
  LV UUID                degnqJ-5KOJ-IW6t-FPJx-5xhy-DUTa-jaWVLY
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time aliot-work, 2013-06-24 14:31:07 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                23,24 GiB
  Current LE             5949
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/aliot-work-vg/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                aliot-work-vg
  LV UUID                beExpf-NH3n-1CZL-BnLp-eAm3-jrpl-WTBu7U
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time aliot-work, 2013-06-24 14:31:17 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                207,13 GiB
  Current LE             53025
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do, if you can some how plug in your new hard drive at the same time the old one is plugged in:

1) Boot into a liveCD or liveUSB of a linux distro (any distro!)

2) Identify which `/dev/sdX` each one is (your 256 is likely `/dev/sdb` and the 512 will be `/dev/sdX` where x can be b, c, d...) Check out `gparted` and see what you see on the top right (`sudo apt-get install gparted` if you don't have it installed and you booted into a debian/ubuntu based distro)

[image]

3) Now that you know which is which (Make sure you do!) run the following command. For the purpose of this command I'll assume that your smaller SSD is /dev/sdb while the larger is /dev/sdc

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

4) This will take a while, a long while. Once it's done, open up gparted and you'll notice that the there's a 256 GB portion that should match your other 256 GB with 256 GB free at the end. Simply extend your main partition into the unallocated space at the end and you should be good to go.

I'm not sure that this will work properly with the encryption + LVM, but I don't see any glaring reasons why not.

Comment: Thanks for your help musher!

Now I have to find how to extand my home partition in LVM with unallocated space: http://askubuntu.com/questions/518511/extend-lvm-with-unallocated-space-of-a-ssd

Best regards.

Comment: No problem. Be sure to mark it as the answer if you'd consider it to be so