# upgrading from a 256gb ssd drive to a bigger one

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption, ssd, clonezilla

My laptop came with a 256gb SSD disk. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on it and activated the disk encryption when I installed it (as far as I know you can't disable it afterwards, can I?)

Anyway I don't have any diskspace left on it (about 100gb of files on it, then a few programs and a few vm's (including a windows one for the whole Adobe stuff)). Sure I could copy files, that I don't need at the time to an NAS or what ever and then get them back, but as a lazy person, I don't like to do that ;). Therefore I'm thinking about getting a bigger SSD (like 512gb).

If possible I'd like to avoid installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu and install/configure all the things I have now. So is it possible to just clone the disk (with something like Clonezilla or `dd`)? What will happen with the additional 256gb can I integrate them in the partition (although it's encrypted)? Or can I just use it as a second partition?

Btw. I've found this question: [How can I can clone or ghost my system drive to restore it to a bigger HD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6615/how-can-i-can-clone-or-ghost-my-system-drive-to-restore-it-to-a-bigger-hd) but it doesn't really answer the question, what will happen with the additional disk space on the bigger disk and there ain't no disk encryption in the game.

Edit: Meanwhile I've found this one: [How to migrate to a bigger ssd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517724/how-to-migrate-to-a-bigger-ssd), which seams to be what I'm looking for. Still the questions about the disk encryption remains. Will I be able to extend the partition?

Comment: I'm not so sure about encrypted drives, but normally a drive is cloned to the new one with the exact partition layout, including size. So, your new drive will have a bunch of extra space after your OS and EFI partitions. Again, I'm not sure about encryption (if it'll even work), but if the clone works, your new drive will end up with blank space at the end where a partition can be created.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the encryption? Maybe while booted run a dd or something to copy the encrypted content to an external harddrive or something?

Comment: Did you enable encryption during the installation or using an option built into the computer?

Comment: @Zacharee1 during the installation. I now first have to enter the key, before the laptop boots and get's to the login screen. As far as I know that's a full disk encryption then.